# Batch to count number of emails

Tags: apex, email, batch

am developing one Batch apex which will count number of Emails associated with Case object.It will store the count in a field "No of Emails "  , InboundEmail Count , OutboundEmailCount on case. I am confuse in how can i write SOQL query and how it will execute.

```
global class EmailCounterBatch implements Database.batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{

    global string query;

    global EmailCounterBatch (){

        //Query to fetch email messages received on Cases last 24 hours 

        query = 'SELECT Id,Count_of_Outbound_Emails__c (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessages ) FROM Case Where LastModifiedDate = TODAY ';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);     
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        List<EmailMessage> emList = new List<EmailMessage>();
        Map<Id, Integer> caseEmailCountMap = new  Map<Id, Integer>(); 
        Integer emailCount ; 


        List<Case> csList = [SELECT Id,Count_of_Outbound_Emails__c FROM Case Where LastModifiedDate = TODAY ];

        for (Case cs : csList){
            emailCount = emailCount + cs.EmailMessages.size();
            caseEmailCountMap.put(cs.Id , emailCount) ; 
        }
        system.debug('----> scope' + scope);

        /*for(sObject eMessage: scope){

        // Calculate EmailMessages on Cases for today

        }

        if(emList.size()>0){

            //Update the counter variables here
        } */
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){} 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        EmailCounterBatch emailCounterBatch = new EmailCounterBatch ();
        database.executeBatch(emailCounterBatch ,200);
    }
}
```

Please suggest modifications in above code !!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend instead using [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). You don't need to write a single line of code. Just configure your two `Lookup Rollup Summary` records, and their detail pages will have a <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button that will run the batch you are trying to write for you. If you want to run this logic through a trigger, the package also supports that behavior.

The Inbound configuration would look something like:

[image: Inbound Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run a query just on the cases, then perform an AggregateQuery result to get the emails for those cases. Here's what that would look like:

```
public class BatchCaseUpdate implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQUeryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Case[] scope) {
        Map<Boolean, Map<Id, Integer>> results = new Map<Boolean, Map<Id, Integer>> {
            true => new Map<Id, Integer>(), false => new Map<Id, Integer>()
        };
        for(Case record: scope) {
            results.get(true).put(record.Id, 0);
            results.get(false).put(record.Id, 0);
        }
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, Incoming incoming, ParentId id FROM EmailMessage 
                                     WHERE ParentId IN :scope GROUP BY Incoming, ParentId]) {
            results.get((Boolean)result.get('incoming')).put((Id)result.get('id'), ((Decimal)result.get('sum')).intValue());
        }
        for(Case record: scope) {
            record.Incoming_Count__c = results.get(true).get(record.Id);
            record.Outgoing_Count__c = results.get(false).get(record.Id);
        }
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```